# Error 1052: Column 'metric_name' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql, grafana, mysql-error-1052

```
SELECT b.target_host                              AS 'host',
       a.target_ip                                AS 'Target',
       a.monitor_type                             AS 'Type Monitor',
       Concat (a.metric_name, "", a.metric_value) AS "metric name value"
FROM   pm_sis_raw_metrics AS a
       INNER JOIN pm_sis_hs_metrics AS b
               ON a.id = b.id
WHERE  metric_value > 80
       AND ( metric_name = "utilization"
              OR metric_name = "physical memory used %"
              OR metric_name = "disk/file system/[c]/percent full"
              OR metric_name = "% packets good" )
```

> Error 1052: Column 'metric_name' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Qualify your columns! I.e. `tablename.columnname`.

Comment: Is column `metric_name` contains in both tables? If so, you need to supply which table is it coming from. Example `a.metric_name` or `b.metric_name` in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Change it to `a.metric_name`

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify the table alias with the column name  like a.metric_name in where cause.